# JetBrains academy question confusion about converting decimals to a given radix

Tags: java

I've been doing a lot of learning on the JetBrains academy over the past few weeks, but a lot of the questions can be quite confusing. Usually I am able to figure out how to do it, but there's a question on converting decimals to a given radix that I just don't understand the wording of. It is as follows:

> Now let's implement a simple converter. It will convert the given decimal number to the given radix. You should support three radices with prefixes:
>
> binary (0b);
> octal (0);
> hexadecimal (0x).
>
> To get a string with the answer, use the Long.toString(sourceNumber, destinationRadix) expression. Note that the expected output is a String, because Java implicitly converts 0/0b/0x concatenated numbers to their decimal representation.*
>
> This stage is auto-graded. The grader will input two lines (a number and a radix) and check that your output is the correct number representation in the given radix. Don't forget about the prefix!

Below is the provided code that they start us off with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num = scanner.nextInt();
            int thing = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toOctalString(num));
            int answer = thing % 10;
            System.out.println(answer);
            
            
    }
}
```

Does anyone understand what is being asked of me, and could perhaps help me to understand the steps I should take to solve this problem? I would like to say I've given it a good shot on my own, but since I don't understand the question at all, I haven't been able to do anything with it.

Comment: Start here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Comment: Look at the _javadoc_ for class [java.lang.Long](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html), in particular the following methods: `toBinaryString`, `toHexString`, `toOctalString` and `toString(long, int)`. Note that **radix 2** means binary, radix 8 means octal, radix 10 means decimal and radix 16 means hexadecimal (or "hex").

Comment: If I understand the assignment correctly, your program is to take two inputs, like "15 8" and then you have to output "17", since in octal 15 is represented as "17". The input could also be "0b1110 16" and then your program should output "E" because that's how the value 15 is represented in hex. Though I find the text in the assignment confusing. Can you not ask them for example input and output?